# После парсинга программа уходит в аут и ничего не делает

Tags: python-3.x, парсер, selenium

Парсер получает информацию, после чего записывает ее в эксель, данные он получает нормально, но после этого почему-то уходит в аут и все.

````
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import xlsxwriter
from time import sleep
import random

class Parser():
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    def parse_name_and_href(self):
        try:
            self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
            self.driver.get('https://sferacar.ru/katalog-avtomobilej?type=22&order_by=cost_ru:asc')
            self.content = self.driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'auto')
            self.urls = self.driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//div[@class ="auto-content"]/a')
            self.urls = [a.get_attribute('href') for a in self.urls]

            self.button = self.driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'btn')
            self.button.click()
            self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20)


            while len(self.content) < 30:
                self.button = self.driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'btn')
                self.button.click()
                self.urls = self.driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class ="auto-content"]/a')
                self.content = self.driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'auto')
                print(len(self.content))
                sleep(random.randint(0,1))
            print('Done!!')




            self.content = [cell.text for cell in self.content]
            print(self.content)

            self.urls = [a.get_attribute('href') for a in self.urls]
            print(self.urls)
            self.probeg = self.probego(self.urls)
            print('Done!')

            self.write_in_exel(self.content,self.urls,self.probeg)
            self.driver.close()
        finally:
            self.driver.close()
    def probego(self,href):

        options = Options()
        options.headless = True
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
        all_prob = []
        try:
            for url in href:
                driver.get(url)
                probeg = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,'auto-chars-value')
                probeg = [cell.text for cell in probeg]

                if 'Бензин' in probeg or 'бензин' in probeg:
                    all_prob.append(probeg[3:5])
                    sleep(random.randint(0,1))
                else:
                    all_prob.append(probeg[2:4])
                    sleep(random.randint(0,1))
            print(all_prob)
        finally:
            driver.close()
        return all_prob

    def write_in_exel(self,content,urls,probeg):
        con = []
        name = 'catalog'
        k = 0

        if exists(f'{name}.xlsx') == False:
            self.workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('catalog.xlsx')
        else:
            while exists(f'{name}.xlsx') == True:
                k +=1
                name+=str(k)
        self.workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(f'{name}.xlsx')
        self.worksheet = self.workbook.add_worksheet()


        try:
            self.worksheet.write('A1', 'Название авто')
            self.worksheet.write('B1', 'Год')
            self.worksheet.write('C1', 'Пробег по РФ')
            self.worksheet.write('D1', 'Пробег')
            self.worksheet.write('E1', 'Объем двигателя')
            self.worksheet.write('F1', 'Цена')
            self.worksheet.write('G1', 'Ссылка')
            self.begin = 2
            for y in content:
                string = y.split('\n')
                del string[3:5]
                string = string[0:-2]
                con.append(string)
            for j, (auto,year,ob,cost) in enumerate(con,start=self.begin):
                self.worksheet.write(f'A{j}', auto)
                self.worksheet.write(f'B{j}', year)
                self.worksheet.write(f'F{j}', cost)
                self.worksheet.write(f'E{j}', ob)
            for j, (in_rus,not_in_rus) in enumerate(probeg, start=self.begin):
                self.worksheet.write(f'C{j}',in_rus)
                self.worksheet.write(f'D{j}',not_in_rus)
            for j,(href) in enumerate(urls,start=self.begin):
                self.worksheet.write(f'G{j}', href)
            
        finally:
            self.workbook.close()



p = Parser()
p.parse_name_and_href()```
````

Comment: Делает именно то, что написано. добавь except и узнаешь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код рабочий, заговздка оказалась в том, что у него низкая скорость обработки, которую я принял за зависание

Comment: Это больше похоже на комментарий к основному вопросу